# Как плавно повернуть камеру в направлении определенной точки во three js?

Tags: three.js

Я использую следующий код:

```
start_rotation = new Euler().copy(camera.rotation);
camera.lookAt(target);
end_rotation = new Euler().copy(camera.rotation);
camera.rotation.copy(start_rotation);
```

Здесь я сохраняю начальные данные камеры о вращении. Затем использую camera.lookAt для установки желаемого направления камеры к точке. Сохраняю положение камеры и сбрасываю значения в первоначальное состояние. А далее анимирую вращение камеры от начального и до конечного состояния.

В целом все работает, но есть одна проблема. Я не контролирую, каким будет само вращение. В идеале я хотел бы сам задавать это (1. Камера повернется по часовой стрелке. 2. Камера повернется против часовой стрелки. 3. Будет выбран кратчайший из двух предыдущих вариантов).

Comment: Может быть этот ответ https://stackoverflow.com/a/42721392/4045502 и этот пост с форума https://discourse.threejs.org/t/solved-move-items-around-a-sphere/1877/13?u=prisoner849 подкинут некоторые идеи о контроле за направлением вращения.